# Creating Bigrams Phrases of a Column in Pandas using Gensim and attaching it to the to same dataframe

Tags: pandas, nlp, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I am trying to built a predictive model using address data. I have transformed the address data into a bigram model using **Gensim Phrases**  but I am facing  issues while transforming the address data into the corresponding bigrams and attaching as a separate column which can be further used for countvectorization.

My code

**Gensim Bigram Phrases model**

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
adj_addr=data['Clean_addr'].values.tolist()
sentence_stream = [doc.split(" ") for doc in adj_addr]
bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=100, threshold=2)
```

---

**Sample input from column of dataframe**

```
SUITE 7001 70/F INTERNATIONAL FINANCE CENTRE TWO  8 FINANCE ST CENTRAL HONG HONG KONG
QUALCOMM INTERNATIONAL INC. 9 QUEENS RD CENTRAL 27TH FLOOR HONG KONG
SAMUEL CHEN COMPANY LIMITED 25 CHIU LUNG ST CHIU LUNG BUILDING 4TH FLOOR CENTRAL HONG KONG
```

**Expected output(New data after passing the gensim phrase model)**

```
SUITE 7001 70/F INTERNATIONAL_FINANCE CENTRE TWO 8_FINANCE ST CENTRAL_HONG HONG_KONG
QUALCOMM INTERNATIONAL INC. 9 QUEENS_RD CENTRAL 27TH FLOOR HONG_KONG
SAMUEL CHEN COMPANY_LIMITED 25 CHIU LUNG_ST CHIU LUNG BUILDING 4TH_FLOOR CENTRAL_HONG KONG
```

**I am not able to replace the corresponding addresses with the respective bigrams from gensim 
 phraseses model iteratively  .** **My expected output is to replace all the old addresses with newly generated bigram phrases .  So that i can pass it to a countvectorizer**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ,INTERNATIONAL_FINANCE (underscore). Phrases will basically create bigrams with underscore .International and finance  will be combined into form INTERNATIONAL_FINANCE

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ,these underscore bigram  are created based on the training data provided gensim phrases.